# Combinatorics test problem; what did I do wrong?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**The problem:** Twelve chairs in a row are to be occupied by eight students and scientists Newton, Einstein, Edison, and Tesla. These four scientists arrive before the eight students and decide to choose their chairs so that each scientist will be between two students. In how many ways can the scientists Newton, Einstein, Edison, and Tesla choose their chairs?

**My approach:** Since there are 4 scientists (S) and 8 kids (K), we know they will be arranged as: K S K S K S K S K, with 3 kids left over. So we have ensured every teacher is between two kids. So to count how many ways to add in the 3 kids left over, we simply choose any existing K to add an additional K. So we have 5C3 ways to select those, times 4! arrangements of the scientists, 5C3 * 4! = 240.

**Answer Key:** Imagine the eight students standing in a row before they are seated. There are 7 spaces between them, each of which may be occupied by at most one of the four scientists. The arrangement may be counted by assigning a different position to each scientist. There are 7P4 ways = 840 ways to do this.

The answer key looks more intuitive than my approach, but I still can't see where I went wrong. Am I missing something obvious? I'd appreciate any help on this!

Comment: What do you mean "choose any existing K to add an additional K"?  Why can't we choose a scientist to add a kid.  And what if we want to add the second left over kid not to any scientist or to any previous kid but to the first left over kid.

Answer (score 2):

You have missed cases where more than one of the three kids is added in the same space.  You need to compute the number of weak compositions of $3$ from $5$ parts which you can do with stars and bars.  I get $7 \choose 4$, which when multiplied by $4!$ for the order of the scientists gives $7P4$ as desired.